# Mapping rows of a table to values of an object without repeating myself

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a data array that is made up of two objects.  I need to loop through the data array and put the values of the same key on the same row.  For example all key's = 'a' need to go on the same row but on a different column.  How can I achieve this without repeating myself as I have done in the examples below?

Here is my data structure

```
const data = [{a:1. b:2, c:3, d:3},{a:2, b:5, c:1, d:5}] 
<table className="table study">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            {data.map((item, key) =>  <th key={key}>{item.a}
            </th>
            )}
          </tr>  
          <tr>
            <td>Title A</td>
            {data.map((item, key) => (
              <td key={key}>{item.a}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Title B</td>
            {data.map((item, key) => (
              <td key={key}>{item.b}</td>
            ))}
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Title C</td>
            {data.map((item, key) =>  <td key={key}>{item.c}
            </td>)}
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something along these lines:

```
const data = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 3 }, { a: 2, b: 5, c: 1, d: 5 }];
<table className="table study">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th />
      {data.map((item, key) => <th key={key}>{item.a}</th>)}
    </tr>
    {Object.keys(data[0]).map(key => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>Title {key.toUpperCase()}</td>
          {data.map((item, idx) => <td key={key+idx}>{item[key]}</td>)}
        </tr>
      );
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: this does not make the keys unique, which is a problem since React expects unique keys for it's diffing algorithms to work optimally.

Comment: Beside the key problem you point out this is a very nice solution! Bu I think it assumes all the objects are a unique shape right?

Comment: @devserkan you are right. Given how the problem was setup, it seemed like this is what the OP was assuming. However, if the key doesn't exist in one of the objects contained in the array, it will simple return undefined and the result will be an empty cell in the table. However, this is assuming that the first object in the array contains all possible keys, so some logic should be implemented to get all of the unique keys.

Comment: Yes, this is what OP needs right now and solves the problem.

Comment: Yes the first object in the array will contain all the possible keys so this does solve the problem. Such a shame  the key validation causing errors because it is such an elegant solution!

Comment: @marcuspetty if the combination of the key and value will always be unique, then key={key+item[key]} will work (don't change it in the `<th>` part though, since those will now be unique). Would that work? Or is it possible these wouldn't be unique?

Comment: @BrooksLybrand unfortunately there will be cases where they wouldn't be unique

Comment: @marcuspetty I edited my solution. Adding the index of the column should now make the keys unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the data before using it.

I find its easier to modify data into a usable shape when I run into problems like this.

```js
// Can have different keys across objects (if you want)
const rawData = [
  { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 3 },
  { a: 2, b: 5, c: 1, d: 5 },
  { e: 2, f: 5, c: 1, d: 5 },
  { b: 5, c: 1, e: 5 },
];

// Flattens to { key: [...values] }
const flattenedData = rawData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  for (const key in curr) {
    if (!curr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      continue;
    }

    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    }

    acc[key].push(curr[key]);
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

const Table = ({ data }) => (
  <table className="table study">
    <tbody>
      {Object.keys(data).map(rowKey => (
        <tr key={rowKey}>
          <th>Title {rowKey.toUpperCase()}</th>
          {data[rowKey].map((item, cellKey) => (
            <td key={cellKey}>{item}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Table data={flattenedData} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```